# setState callback not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a working app and am just trying to set the state to `loading: true` while my app makes a submission call so I can show a loading screen. Because I want to make sure I set the state *before* making the loading call, I use a callback. However I'm not seeing my loading update with the code below:

```
submitSecurityAnswer = () => {
    const { submit, handleError, navigate } = this.props;
    const { answer } = this.state;

    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      console.log('setState', this.state)
      try {
        submit({ answer, ...this.props }).then(({ errors, status }) => {
          this.setState({ answer: '' });
          if (status && status === 200) {
            navigate();
          } else if (status === 401) {
            this.setState({ showError: true });
          } else {
            handleError(errors[0]);
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };
```

When I check my console log I see that the state has not updated and loading is still false.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If I understood what you are trying to do correctly your `this.setState({loading:false})` should be right before or after `navigate();`

Comment: actually if you change `this.setState({ answer: '' });` to `this.setState({ answer: '', loading:false });` it should work too

Comment: yea, I'm trying to `this.setState({loading:false})` before the `submit()`

Comment: then put it before the submit() function

Comment: You are calling `this.setState({ loading: true })` and `this.setState({ loading: false })` at the same time. The latter call kind of overrides the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening, because you are calling `this.setState({ loading: false });` in the end of your function.

You are setting `loading: true` and `loading: false` at the same time. When you your callback is invoking, the last setState function is also changed state value to false.

You should set loading state to false after request was received:

```
submitSecurityAnswer = () => {
  const { submit, handleError, navigate } = this.props;
  const { answer } = this.state;

  this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
    console.log('setState', this.state)
    try {
      submit({ answer, ...this.props }).then(({ errors, status }) => {
        this.setState({ answer: '' });
        if (status && status === 200) {
          navigate();
        } else if (status === 401) {
          this.setState({ showError: true, loading: false });
        } else {
          handleError(errors[0]);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Here you have called setState again in the callback function of setState. Can we do this? I mean should we write setState inside callback of setState?

Answer (score 2):

That because you are setting `loading` to `false` before the async operation has completed.
Just move `this.setState({ loading: false });` inside the `callback`;

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> I tried removing that but saw the same results

I didn't say to remove it just **move** it inside the callback of `setstate`.
What happens is that you are setting it to `true` then `false` at the same call stack iteration and not waiting for the async operation to complete.

Consider this scenario which is similar to your code :
In this example i set the `loading` back to false before the async operation (`setTimeout`) is finished, hence i'm just overriding the previous state without waiting.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      message: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          message: 'we have data'
        });
        console.log(this.state);
      }, 500);
    });

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
  const {message, loading} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <div>{message}</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The fix will be to move the next state change inside the callback:
In this example i moved the line `this.setState({ loading: false });` inside the callback after the async operation has completed and this fixed the unwanted behavior.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      message: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          message: 'we have data'
        });
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }, 500);
    });

  }

  render() {
    const {message, loading} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
       {loading ? <div>loading...</div> : <div>{message}</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i didn't say remove, i said move it inside the callback function. see my examples